# what is a good tacit form of sum(1/(1+x)^y) in J

Tags: j, tacit-programming

As a beginner exercise I tried to calculate the following sum in J, `sum(1/(1+0.03)^n for n = 1 to 30` using `+/%(1 + 0.03)^ >:i.30`.  How can I write this into a simple tacit form? all I tried are significantly uglier than the explicit form above like `>:@[ (+/&:%)@:^  >:&i.@]`

Comment: Tacit form works much more smoothly for some calculations than others. As values need to be applied irregularly within a formula, the overhead of passing them through to those points becomes burdensome. This fact is discussed (in a non-J context) in a blog post, http://evincarofautumn.blogspot.com/2012/02/why-concatenative-programming-matters.html , under the section heading "The Dark Side". In the formula at hand I think the two arguments are not inherently clumsy, but are instead handled nicely by a hook as Tikkanz demonstrates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start with

```
+/@:%@((1 + 0.03) ^ >:@i.) 30
```

You can make the 0.03 a left argument using a fork, but using a hook can be cleaner

```
(1 + 0.03) +/@:%@([ ^ >:@i.@]) 30   NB. use fork
(1 + 0.03) +/@:%@(^ >:@i.) 30       NB. use hook
```

The same operation (increment) is being performed on both the left and right arguments to `^`. That is a hint that `&` ([Compose](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/d630v.htm)) may be useful.

```
0.03 +/@:%@(^&>: i.) 30         NB. apply increment to both left & right arg
```

Comment: I like how you identified increment into something common to both sides, and also your use of hook. I prefer Cap in this case, so the phrasing I favor at the moment is `formula=: [: +/ [: % ( ^&>: i.)`

Answer (score 1):

When I want a tacit function I often let `13 :` bang it out for me. In this case, some variations:

```
   13 : '+/ %((1+0.03)^1+i.y)'
[: +/ [: % 1.03 ^ 1 + i.

   13 : '+/ %((1+0.03)^>:i.y)'
[: +/ [: % 1.03 ^ [: >: i.
```

And with `1+0.03` or whatever as a leftargument:

```
   13 : '+/ %(x^1+i.y)'
[: +/ [: % [ ^ 1 + [: i. ]

   13 : '+/ %(x^>:i.y)'
[: +/ [: % [ ^ [: >: [: i. ]
```

There are way too many caps (`[:`) to call it less ugly, though, but that's a start.